# multiple DOM manipulation functions with javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm playing with d3 and am trying to write a very simple page to show my d3 examples for future reference.

Essentially my page shows the result of the d3 code (force layout from Mike Bostock in this instance) and then, below it. embeds the relevant javascript into the page for reference.

I have a simple jQuery '.load' script to pull-in the javascript function, which works fine.  And, i'm using highlight.js to do the syntax formatting on the code which has been pulled in.  Which also works.

At the moment I have two buttons, one to load the text of the script and one to do the formatting.  This works fine.

But, i'd like to have it all work on page load.

I've tried to combine the two scripts in the one button as a test (as shown below) but the syntax highlighting just wont work.  But the syntax button by itself works fine.

It is almost as though the DOM manipulation of the .load event doesn't complete or something??

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta source="http://codepen.io/planetoftheweb/pen/CdqcD">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/style.css">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Syntax highlighter references -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yandex.st/highlightjs/7.3/styles/googlecode.min.css">
    <script src="http://yandex.st/highlightjs/7.3/highlight.min.js"></script>

    <!-- d3 script for this example -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/new_chart.js"></script>


    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body, .stage {
          background: white; 
        }
    </style>

    <script src="../d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script>
        function code() {
            show_code();
            format_text();
        }
        function show_code() {
            $('.code pre code').load('JS/new_chart.js');
            $('pre code').each(function(i, e) {hljs.highlightBlock(e)});
        };
        function format_text() {

            $('pre code').each(function(i, e) {hljs.highlightBlock(e)});
        };
    </script>

    </head>
    <body onload = "new_chart()">
    <div class = "page_title">
        <h1>D3 example</h1>
        <h2>Force layout</h2>
    </div>
    <div class = "chart" id ='chart'></div>
    <div class = "code">
        <button id="show_code" onclick="code();">show code</button>
        <button onclick="format_text();">format</button>
        <pre><code>

        </code></pre>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you've got is because the load happens asynchronously, so the first call to the syntax highlighter happens before the code has been loaded. Try this:

```
<div class="code">
    <button id="show_code">show code</button>
    <pre><code></code></pre>
</div>
```

```js
$('#show_code').click(function() {
    var $codeContainer = $('pre code', $(this).closest('.code'));
    $codeContainer.load('JS/new_chart.js', function() {
        hljs.highlightBlock($codeContainer[0]);
    });        
});
```

Note that the highlighter call is placed in a 'callback' function parameter of load. This means it will be executed after the `load` request has completed. I have also made the loader work on the specific `.code` block which relates to the button which was clicked - just in case you need to have more than 1 per page.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the quick reply.
I did try it with a 1 second delay between the two functions but that didn't work either.  Why would that be?

Comment: That would have worked if the `load()` took less than 1 second, but you can't guarantee that it would so it's not a workable solution.